# Tor install in Kali linux will not work?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, tor-install, kali-linux

I have downloaded Tor and tried to install but when I try to open the install it just opens a text file. Is there something else that I need?  What am I doing wrong?  Sorry this is the Tor I downloaded linux64-8.5a4_en-US.tar.xz and I am running Kali GNU/Linux Rolling 64-bit.

Comment: just extract the linux64-8.5a4_en-US.tar.xz file double click it double click on installer icon (not Browser folder)

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the community and definitely thank you for using Tor =D

I just realized you mentioned Kali linux.
I'm also going to assume you meant you downloaded the Tor Browser Bundle?

With Kali Linux, you are logged in as root user(default but not the only option).
Tor Browser Bundle DOES NOT run with root permissions, it will let you know that if you manage to run it.

You will need to create a new user and log in under that to run Tor Browser Bundle.

The other way is to just use Tor that comes with Kali, and setup a proxy to tunnel a browsers traffic through Tor.

You will need to extract the downloaded Tor Browser Bundle to a directory, then navigate to that directory.

Once there, you will need to mark the Tor Browser Launcher file as executable. This can be achieved by right clicking it, choosing properties, and selecting the permissions tab and you will be presented with an option to mark it as executable.

Click apply/save/ok and you should now be able to open the launcher as intended.